Is $F_X(t) > F_Y(t)$ a sufficient and necessary condition of $\mathbb{P}(X < Y) > 0.5$
I asked the question when conducting Mann–Whitney U test using the scipy implementation. The null hypothesis for one of the one-sided tests is $F_X(t) > F_Y(t)$, where $F$ denotes a CDF. I wonder if it's equivalent to saying $\mathbb{P}(X < Y) > 0.5$, where $\mathbb{P}(X < Y)$ denotes the probability of random sample from $X$ is smaller than that from $Y$.

It is certainly sufficient, it is absolutely not necessary. The problem is that the scipy page you provided a link to is simply wrong, on so many levels (as are most textbooks, references, etc. when it comes to Mann-Whitney U test). So disregard what scipy says completely (as to what it dcoes, you be judge, but it certainly does not handle ties as it should...)

@jginestet, do you have a pointer to why the scipy page description is wrong and what's the more proper way to handle ties?

Let's start with the null as descriped by scypy: it is not a test of whether 2 distributions are the same, nor is it a test of location. It can be, but only under some (very strict, and practically never realized) additional conditions. Best place to start is the Mann-Whitney paper; it is freely available here:  https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-18/issue-1/On-a-Test-of-Whether-one-of-Two-Random-Variables/10.1214/aoms/1177730491.full

I read the paper. The null appears to be indeed f=g according to "Under the hypothesis f = g the probability of obtaining a given U ...`. What would be the null for Mann-Whitney U test your words?

The most "consistent" null, not requiring any additional assumption (beside i.i.d) is P(X>Y) $\ne$ P(Y<X). If the null were F=G, note that rejecting the null only allows you to say  can say F$\ne$G, which leads nowhere (is F "better" in some way? What is different, the mean, the variance, the skewness, a bit of all three?) If the null is simply F=G you can not make any useful inference.. To do so requires stringent additional assumptions (which ideally should be rolled in the null), such as symmetry of both F & G, or that F & G are exactly the same, just shifted, which are untestable.

Do you mean the null is P(X>Y) = P(Y<X) rather than P(X>Y) ≠ P(Y<X)? Is there a proof that shows the U statistic follows a normal distribution under this null?

The proper formulation of the null is $P(X>Y)+\frac 1 2 P(X=Y)=0.5$ (to account for ties), or $P(X>Y)=P(Y<X)$. These 2 formulations are mathematically identical, since both $X$ and $Y$ get the same contribution from ties.. The formulation of $P(X>Y)=0.5$ is only valid if there are no ties, which can be assumed if at least one distribution is continuous. But in the real world, with "limited" resolution of the measuring instruments, all distributions are practically-speaking discrete, with ties.  ...cont

...cont. The U statistic computes exactly what the complete null formulation says; it looks at all possible pairwise comparisons between data in X and Y, adds 1 if the X sample is larger, and adds 1/2 if the 2 samples are equal. So yes, the normal approximation holds (for larger samples, typically >20). See the wiki page, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test

A trivial counterexample for "$P(X < Y) > 0.5$" does not necessarily imply $F_X(t) > F_Y(t)$ for all $t$ is letting $X \sim N(0, 1)$ and $Y \equiv 1$. Then $P(X < Y) = P(X < 1) > P(X < 0) = 0.5$, while for all $t \geq 1$, we have $F_X(t) = \Phi(t) < F_Y(t) = 1$.
Unlike other answer's /comment's assertion, I don't think the sufficiency holds either, because $X$ and $Y$ may be correlated.  For example, let $X \sim N(0, 1)$, then define $Y$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
Y = (1 - \varepsilon)X + \varepsilon(X + 1),
\end{align*}
where $\varepsilon \sim B(1, p)$ is independent of $X$. It then follows that
\begin{align*}
F_Y(t) &= P(Y \leq t) = P((1 - \varepsilon)X + \varepsilon(X + 1) \leq t) \\
&= P(X \leq t, \varepsilon = 0) + P(X + 1 \leq t, \varepsilon = 1) \\
&= P(X \leq t)P(\varepsilon = 0) + P(X + 1 \leq t)P(\varepsilon = 1) \\
&= (1 - p)\Phi(t) + p\Phi(t - 1) \\
&< \Phi(t) = F_X(t). 
\end{align*}
However,
\begin{align*}
P(X < Y) = P(\varepsilon = 1) = p. 
\end{align*}
So for $p \in (0, \frac{1}{2}]$, we cannot have $P(X < Y) > 0.5$. In order to make the sufficiency direction holds, we need more condition -- an easy additional condition could be that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and one of them is continuous.

Ah, good catch on the correlation (+1).  I was thinking in terms of the Mann-Whitney test and subconsciously folding in the assumptions of independence and continuity, but that wasn't explicitly part of the question.

Clever one and the sufficient condition does follow from the counter example!

Independence is "always" a condition of any statistical test. If not i.i.d, then we can find counter examples to absolutely anything

@Zhanxiong, very clever counterexample. But it is not a counterexample, as the proper formulation should be $P(X>Y)+\frac 1 2 P(X=Y)>0.5$, or $P(X>Y)>P(X<Y)$. The OP's formulation assumes there are no ties; but your "counter-example" has lots of ties (particularly if $p<.5$). If you use the correct formulation, which adds 1/2 for each tie, then the probability is $p+\frac {1-p} {2}=\frac 1 2 + \frac p 2 > \frac 1 2$. The OP's formulation assumes no ties; for your counterexample, which has lots of ties, one has to use the more rigorous formulation, and then the counter exampe no longer works.

@jginestet I see your point, thanks.  This answer is intended to serve an answer to the primitive formulation of th question without attempting to impose unstated conditions (e.g., I just treat $X, Y$ as two most general r.v.s satisfying the conditions in the title, but not embed them to the context of Mann-Whitney testing).

The OP specifically mentioned Mann-Whitney U; but fair enough...

Just contributing some details to the other answers and comments. Regarding sufficiency, suppose that we have two independent random variables $X\sim F$ and $Y\sim G$, and that $X$ is absolutely continuous. Also, suppose* that $F(t)>G(t)$, for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$. First, notice the well known result that defining $G^{-1}(u) =\inf\,\{t:G(t)\geq u\}$, and introducing the random variable $U=G(Y)$, it follows that
$$
  P(U\leq u)=P(G(Y)\leq u)=P(Y\leq G^{-1}(u))=G(G^{-1}(u))=u,
$$
meaning that $U\sim\text{Uniform}(0,1)$, and of course $\mathbb{E}[G(Y)]=\mathbb{E}[U]=1/2$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
  P(X<Y) &= \int_\mathbb{R} P(X<Y\mid Y=t)\,dG(t) \\
  &= \int_\mathbb{R} P(X<t\mid Y=t)\,dG(t) \\
  &= \int_\mathbb{R} P(X<t)\,dG(t) \qquad\qquad (\text{independence}) \\
  &= \int_\mathbb{R} P(X\leq t)\,dG(t) \qquad\qquad (\text{$X$ is abs. cont.}) \\
  &= \int_\mathbb{R} F(t)\,dG(t) \\
  &> \int_\mathbb{R} G(t)\,dG(t) \;\;\qquad\qquad (\text{using hypothesis *}) \\
  &= \mathbb{E}[G(Y)] = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}

A simple counterexample for necessity follows.
Consider $Y \sim U(0,4)$ and $X \sim U(1,2)$.  Since $P(Y > 2) = 0.5$, clearly $P(X < Y) > 0.5$, but $F_Y(t) < F_X(t)$ for $t \in (4/3,4)$ and $F_Y(t) > F_X(t)$ for $t \in [0, 4/3)$.
For sufficiency, it should be intuitively clear that if $F_Y(t) < F_X(t) \;\forall\;t$, $P(X < Y) > 0.5$.
